# Iterate over multiple parameters with spaces in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a bash script for my RaspberryPi (running Raspbian) that is supposed to take multiple file names as parameter(s) and play one after the other (using `omxplayer`). The basic structure is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ${*}
do
  echo "${f}";
done;
```

Now I have problems when the input filenames contain spaces; in particular, the behaviour seems to be inconsistent. Assume we have two files `test a b` and `test d e` in the same directory. Running above script with different parameters yields this:

```
$ ./test test\ a\ b
test
a
b
$ ./test "test a b"
test
a
b
$ ./test test\ a*
test
a
b
$ ./test "test a*"
test
a*
```

But, curiously:

```
./test "test*"
test a b
test d e
```

Obviously, only this last variant provides the intended output. It is cumbersome to use, however, especially if you want to watch a single file (tab-completion will fill in the whole name) or if one of the folder names in the file's path contains spaces.

What can I do differently in the shellscript so that it will always behave as intended? In particular, both of

```
$./test test*
$./test test\ a\ b test\ d\ e
```

should produce the same output

```
test a b
test d e
```

so the script can be used easily using normal tab-completion.

Comment: In general, `test` is not a good name for an example program, because there is `/usr/bin/test`; It's relevant because people learn from seeing examples; And in this special case, it would be a lot more readable with a different name too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `"$@"` instead of `${*}` (see [Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) in the manual)

```
for f in "$@"; do 
    echo make sure you quote your "$variables" everywhere in the loop
```

There's a shorthand (and more portable) for this:

```
for f do ...
```

`for f; do` would also work in some shells but is not standard.

Comment: The `for f; do` trick does not work in my bash 4.2.39. But instead of using `"$@"` I can stay with the `$*` when I add a IFS='\n' before the for loop.

Comment: `IFS='\n'` means that only linebreaks are separators. `$IFS` is by default set to space, tab and linebreak, i.e. `IFS=' \t\n'`.

Comment: Both forms seem to work fine. I prefer the first version for clarity; in which way is it not as portable? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Raphael, `for i in "$@"` doesn't work in many versions of the Bourne shell when `$#` is 0 (Which is why you often see the `${1+"$@"}` construct). `for f do` is the Bourne shell way to loop over the arguments.

Comment: Is the Bourne shell actually distributed these days?

Comment: @glennjackman With Tru64 no longer maintained and Solaris 11 thankfully giving it up at last, we're probably only left with OpenServer and UnixWare (?). Most major Unices no longer have the Bourne shell (or they do in non-standard places like /usr/sunos/bin/sh or as different names like bsh). There still are a great number of old and not so old systems with /bin/sh as the Bourne shell around though, mostly Solaris.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way is to use a `while` loop in one of two ways:

```
input_cmd|while read i; do
  echo "$i";
done
```

or through process substitution:

```
while read i; do
  echo "$i";
done < <(input_cmd)
```

The latter is a bashism as far as I'm aware, so it may not work in other bourne compatible shells.

Since you are getting the input from the command line, it may be better to stick to the `for` loop solution offered in the previous answer, however.

You should also have a look at `man xargs`, because that is usually the best way to handle exotic command line arguments.

Comment: _the latter_ is a kshism, copied by zsh and bash. When you use `read`, you need the `-r` option and remove the white space characters from `$IFS` (like `IFS= read -r i`) unless you need the special behaviour of `read` if you don't

Comment: But what if the filenames contain newlines?

Comment: @ruakh: that's exactly when `xargs` comes in handy. Last paragraph of my answer.